# Is there a way for `stack --nix` to allow newer versions of ghc to be used?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nix, xmonad

I'm running `stack --nix init` for a new project (xmonad config) and getting `error: attribute 'ghc863' missing, at (string):1:43`; I have ghc 8.6.5 in the environment, and `stack --version` reports: 2.1.3.1 x86_64 hpack-0.32.0. My project is roughly following [this blog post](https://brianbuccola.com/how-to-install-xmonad-and-xmobar-via-stack/) for building XMonad (with exceptions made to do things using Nix where possible), and so far only consists of cloning the three repos into `.xmonad` and running `stack --nix init`; the three repos are: `xmobar`, `xmonad-contrib`, `xmonad`.

Is there a way for `stack --nix` to allow newer versions of ghc to be used? Or are there other possible causes for the issue?

I saw [stack --nix build complains about ghc version mismatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39155853/stack-nix-build-complains-about-ghc-version-mismatch) but felt this didn't really illuminate the issue, though it does suggest possibly alternatives using cabal/nix.

Comment: As a workaround  you could just try a later stackage snapshot.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to do that, other than overriding what is in the source dependencies, which I was about to try;  I just ended up doing `stack init` (without the `--nix`) flag, which sufficed for initializing the project.